# set callback function to return value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Here is my code:

```
function render(){
    var el;
    setTimeout(function(){
      func();
    },1000);
    return el;
  }

function func(){
    //do something here;
}
```

setTimeout is async, so el will be returned before execute func.I want to return el after calling func, how should I write the callback function?

Comment: Do you want the caller of `render` to wait until el is available (as you said el is returned from the function)? If so I'm not sure the @CD answer would work for you.

Comment: You can't. You'll need to rewrite your logic so the things that should depend on the return value of `func` are actually triggered at the end of `func`

Comment: @Gareth, got it. But not sure how to make it work. Any more details about how to do that? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a callback - a function that `el` will be passed to:

```
function render(callback){
    var el;
    setTimeout(function(){
      func();
      callback(el);
    },1000);
  }

function func(){
    //do something here;
}

function elReady(el){
    // use `el`
}
```

So now you can use `render(elReady)`.

Comment: how should the callback function be? Simply function callback(el){return el;} won't work since I want render to return el. Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: the `callback` should contain what ever you'd like to do with `el`, it will be called once `el` is 'ready'.

Comment: well my concern is the same as @PaulGrime commented above

Comment: @YujunWu: If you want a 1000ms delay, then you simply can not return the value you want from `render`. There's no such thing as a synchronous pause in JavaScript *(at least not without blocking)*. You need to change your code to fit the environment, because the environment sure isn't going to change to fit your code.

Comment: +1 but it might help OP to see the callback actually being passed to `render`. This can be confusing at first.